# Laravel ReflectionException (-1) Class country does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I have been trying to understand how to  a multi country website just like multi locale so that a user is redirected to his country specific listings based on his location.

I'm learning laravel and from my learning i have tried something like below which shows an error And need someone to correct me to proceed my learning.

**App\Models\Country.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Country extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'countries';
}
```

**routes\web.php**

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => '{country}', 'middleware' => 'country'], function(){
  Route::get('/', 'Frontend\PagesController@index')->name('welcome');
});
```

**App\Http\Middleware\CountryMiddleware.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Models\Country;
use Closure;
use Request;
use Route;

class CountryMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $countryShortcode = $request->route('country');
           $routeName = $request->route()->getName();
           $routeParameters = $request->route()->parameters();
           if ($request->session()->has('redirect_to_country')) {
               $redirectTo = $request->session()->get('redirect_to_country');
               if ($country === $redirectTo) {
                   $request->session()->forget('redirect_to_country');
               } else {
                   $routeParameters['country'] = $redirectTo;
                   return redirect()->route($routeName, $routeParameters);
               }
           }
           $country = Country::where('country_shortcode', '=', $countryShortcode)
                      ->where('is_active', '=', 1)->first();
           if ($country === null) {
               return redirect('/');
           }
           $request->session()->put('country', $country);
           $request->session()->save();
           return $next($request);
        }
}
```

**Migration: 2018_08_12_225010_create_countries_table.php**

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCountriesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('countries', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('country_name');
            $table->string('country_shortcode')->unique();
            $table->tinyinteger('is_active');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('countries');
    }
}
```

I have created three countries in the database i.e., `United States` with short code `USA`, `United Kingdom` with short code `UK`, `Australia` with short code `AUS`.

When i go to `www.example.com` it says:

> page not found. 
>   And when i go to `www.example.com/USA` it says:
>
> ReflectionException (-1)
>   Class country does not exist

1 - How to solve this?

2 - How to autodetect users location code and redirect to their location route? like users from usa to `www.example.com/USA`.

3 - In my controller, I would like to fetch country code from route and do something like this:

```php
$code = $request->route('country');
Professionals::where('short_code', $code)->latest()->paginate(10);
```

4 - And for `www.example.com` which shows as `not found 404` page. How to show a normal website with all locations. Do I need to specify routes outside the group?

So that the correct professionals in that country are listed according to the users location.

Comment: Do you want please tell me where did you find `$country` in `if ($country === $redirectTo) ` on the middleware ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding the below to the routeMiddleware in App\Http\Kernel.php

```
'country' => \App\Http\Middleware\CountryMiddleware::class,
```

And i have changed the below code in CountryMiddleware

```
if ($country === null) {
               return redirect('/USA');
           }
```

so that default location is usa and any users with incorrect or missing location will be redirected to usa